# Getting Duplicate Requests on server from browser ASP.NET Core 3 Preview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-3.0

i am getting two requests for every request made to server from browser
--> One Request Comes as HTTP/1.1
--> Other Request comes as HTTP/2.0

- Using 3 Preview version of ASP.NET Core
- Only in case of Dynamic request Static content loads via HTTP /1.1 only
- Using Windows server 2016 (AWS) and IIS 10

Logs From server

```
2019-03-17T02:33:23.8121085+00:00 8000000a-0000-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://www.WEbApp.com/   
2019-03-17T02:33:23.8121085+00:00 8000000a-0000-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://www.WEbApp.com/   (ca22a1cb)
2019-03-17T02:33:23.9317375+00:00 8000000a-0000-f800-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Executing endpoint '"WEbApp.GlobalController.GlobalController.Index (WEbApp)"' 
2019-03-17T02:33:23.9444334+00:00 80000010-0000-f900-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Executing endpoint '"WEbApp.GlobalController.GlobalController.Index (WEbApp)
```